# repetitive jmeter http request doesn's show in Aggregate Report listener

Tags: caching, jmeter, performance-testing

I've configured 1 thread, loop count 2 and Aggregate Report as a listener with some http request sampler. Caching is enabled. When I run my test plan I get only one sample of each request in Aggregate Report. Some Cached requests are not even hitting second time to server whereas for some are getting executed again. Can anyone explain what settings I need to configure for getting report of all request samples. Thank you in advance.

[please find image of result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbAI4.png)

Comment: Can you show your test plan and results?

Comment: please checkout result in above link.

Comment: #Samplers hold the Samplers number aggregated, you have 10 per request. so what is the issue?

Comment: there is just one sample for 3 requests whereas 10 samples for remaining. can you tell me why they 3 are not executed more than once?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, JMeter's [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) respects [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers like [Etag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) and [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) so on second requests embedded resources like image, scripts, fonts, styles are being returned from cache, no actual request is being made. This is what real browsers would do.

[image: JMeter cache in action]

If for any reason you want all requests to be executed each time you need to:

1. Tick `Clear cache each iteration` box in the HTTP Cache Manager

   [image: JMeter clear cache]
2. Remove Loop Controller from the Test Plan
3. Set desired number of loops on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

   [image: JMeter Loops Thread GRoup]

See [Using the HTTP Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) for more information on embedded resources caching if needed.

Comment: even though caching is enabled some requests are getting executed in each loop whereas some are getting executed only once.